# JavaScript - GPS position in mobile browser and HTTPS/SSL certificate

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, gps, position

I'm running a web app where users can request a map with their position through gps. In order to do that browsers like Chrome and Safari require an HTTPS protocol, not just http, otherwise call to JS function "getCurrentPosition" will fail. (but on Firefox, for example, it's working)

First question: are there any other possibilities to get user location (through gps, not just by ip)?

If not, the only way (I think) is to switch to https.
Now, app is running on a cheap shared hosting (and I can't do anything about that right now), the only thing that I can do is purchase an SSL certificate in order to enable https protocol.

Second question: hosting offers both ssl certificate with dedicated ip and without dedicated ip. Which is the difference? Well, I know what's a dedicated ip, but for my needs (website + this small app) which advantage could I have from a dedicated ip?

Third question: if I choose a certificate from another CA then I need root access to server in order to install it, is it right?

Last one: some hostings offer SSL with identity verification and without it, how theese last work? I mean, https should't guarrantee encrypted connections with a verified website?

If you have any links please post them, most of resources that I found are too old and they don't talk about acquiring gps data with JS.
Thanks a lot!

EDIT: just for completion: [this page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) is about this deprecated js call for non-secure site. Are there other possibilites to get same result?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. You're asking about hosting, which is off-topic.

Comment: Ok. What about getting position of users with Javascript? It's working on firefox, but not in Chrome and Safari. I'm following this howto: http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_geolocation.asp . Do you have any idea? Are there other ways to get these infos? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First question: are there any other possibilities to get user location
>   (through gps, not just by ip)?

You can track users’ real time location by using Google Maps APIs, I hope below links  will help you.

[Using Google Map Tracks API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569979/using-google-map-tracks-api)

https://developers.google.com/maps/

> Second question: hosting offers both ssl certificate with dedicated ip
>   and without dedicated ip. Which is the difference? Well, I know what's
>   a dedicated ip, but for my needs (website + this small app) which
>   advantage could I have from a dedicated ip?

In the past, SSL requires dedicated IP to secure web applications. But in the mean time, SSL doesn’t require dedicated IP due to SNI technology. If your website hosted on shared IP address, then SNI permits a server to implement multiple certificates on a single IP address.

There are plenty of advantages using a dedicated IP instead of shared IP - read this [article](https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/shared-ip-vs-dedicated-ip-which-one-is-more-beneficial/)

> Third question: if I choose a certificate from another CA then I need
>   root access to server in order to install it, is it right?

Whether you continue with current provider or new one, you don’t need root access of server in order install an SSL certificate.

> Last one: some hostings offer SSL with identity verification and
>   without it, how theese last work? I mean, https should't guarrantee
>   encrypted connections with a verified website?

All SSL certificates are come with industry standard 256 bit encryption and ensures about encrypted connections.  There is varying upon their validation process as below.

- **Domain Validation Certificates** - CA will follow automated validation process and confirm only your control over the domain. You will get this certificate in just minutes.
- **Business Validation Certificates** - CA will check your business existence by verifying official documentations. CA will take 2 to 3 business days to issue your certificate.
- **Extended Validation Certificates** - CA will follow strict validation process and validate legal, physical and operational identity of business. EV SSL will enable most visible sign “the company name in the green address bar”, it will increase trust of your website visitors.

I hope this will helpful for you!